# Re-render Aurelia Dialog

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I am trying get Aurelia Dialog to be up in one route tab, but when I switch tabs, it will not be up anymore.  **Then when I return to the first, it has the dialog still up.**

I have set the host of my Aurelia Dialog to be inside one of my routes (in a custom element).  This causes the dialog to not be present, when I go to another tab.

But when I go back to the first tab, it is not there (of course, because it is not part of the default UI for that route.)  But, I store the state of the dialog, so the Javascript still thinks it is all on the screen (`hasActiveDialog` is true).

**I need a way to tell my Aurelia Dialog that I just need it to re-render.**

I suppose I can try to store the Tags that make the dialog before I switch away, and try to restore them after, but I would rather find a way to tell the dialog to render again what it thinks is on the screen.